# Sort and Filter ListView based on ratings(acquired through an API call) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a listview based on ratings in descending order. I used the Zomato API to get the Restaurants data. On a button click, I want the List to be sorted.

Here is the API call :

```
Future<List<ZomatoCollection>> getCollections(int cityId) async {
    http.Response response = await client.get(NetworkRouter.cityCollections(cityId));
    Map<String,dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body);
    List results = list['collections'];
    return results.map((singleCollection){
      return ZomatoCollection.fromJSON(singleCollection);
    }).toList();
  }
```

Here is the model class for Restaurants and Its API Call :

```
class Restaurant {
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String cuisines;
  final int averageCost;
  final String rating; // Text
  final String ratingColor;

  Restaurant.fromJSON(json):name=json['restaurant']['name'],
  imageUrl = json['restaurant']['thumb'],
  cuisines = json['restaurant']['cuisines'],
  averageCost = json['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'],
  rating = json['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'],
  ratingColor=json['restaurant']['user_rating']['rating_color'];
}
Future<List<Restaurant>> getNearbyCollections(int cityId, int collectionId) async {
    http.Response response = await client.get(NetworkRouter.nearbyCollections(cityId,collectionId));
    Map<String,dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body);
    List results = list['restaurants'];
    return results.map((singleRestaurant){
      return Restaurant.fromJSON(singleRestaurant);
    }).toList();
  }
```

I used ListviewBuilder to display Image, Cuisines, average cost and ratings.
I want to sort the Listview according to the ratings.

Here is the ZomatoCollection model class:

```
class  ZomatoCollection {
  final int collectionId;
  final int restauranteCount;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String url;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  ZomatoCollection.fromJSON(json)
  :title = json['collection']['title'],
  restauranteCount = json['collection']['res_count'],
  imageUrl = json['collection']['image_url'],
  collectionId = json['collection']['collection_id'],
  description = json['collection']['description'],
  url = json['collection']['url'];


}
```

Comment: you can sort the List<ZomatoCollection> using sort() function. Can you show us the Model class of ZomatoCollection?

Comment: class  ZomatoCollection {
  final int collectionId;
  final int restauranteCount;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String url;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  ZomatoCollection.fromJSON(json)
  :title = json['collection']['title'],
  restauranteCount = json['collection']['res_count'],
  imageUrl = json['collection']['image_url'],
  collectionId = json['collection']['collection_id'],
  description = json['collection']['description'],
  url = json['collection']['url'];

  
}

Comment: thanks, so you can do one thing, sort the results List that's storing restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on the restaurant's List. See if it works or not.
for example, your future Restaurant List is stored in variable res. Return res after sorting.

```
  res.sort((a,b) => b.rating.compareTo(a.rating);
);
```

Comment: can you please show me, if any error is coming or how you implemented the solution?

Comment: Future<List<Restaurant>> getNearbyCollectionsBySort(
      int cityId, int collectionId, ) async {
    http.Response response =
        await client.get(NetworkRouter.nearbyCollections(cityId, collectionId));
    Map<String, dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body);
    List results = list['restaurants'];
    List<Restaurant>res = results.map((singleRestaurant) {
      return Restaurant.fromJSON(singleRestaurant);
    }).toList();
    Comparator<Restaurant> ratingComparator= (a,b)=>a.rating.compareTo(b.rating);
    res.sort(ratingComparator);
    return res;
  }

Comment: Ok so the implementation is correct, tryna swap a.rating to b.rating and vice versa. If that doesn't work, please tell us how your rating looks like. We know it's a string, but what's it in that.